# NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException for MySQL query that works in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table with four foreign keys and an image:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| dataset_1_fk | dataset_2_fk | attribute_type_1_fk | attribute_type_2_fk | image |
+--------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Using the name of two datasets, I would like to select the image and names of the two attributes. Here is my Hibernate code:

```
HibernateUtil
    .getCurrentSession()
    .createSQLQuery(
        "SELECT ddm.image, at1.name, at2.name " +
        "FROM dataset_dataset_matrices AS ddm " +
        "  JOIN dataset AS d1 ON d1.id = ddm.dataset_1_fk " +
        "  JOIN dataset AS d2 ON d2.id = ddm.dataset_2_fk " +
        "  JOIN attribute_type AS at1 ON at1.id = ddm.attribute_type_1_fk " +
        "  JOIN attribute_type AS at2 ON at2.id = ddm.attribute_type_2_fk " +
        "WHERE d1.name = :dataset_1 AND d2.name = :dataset_2"
    )
    .setString("dataset_1", dataset_1)
    .setString("dataset_2", dataset_2)
    .list();
```

I receive this error when it executes:

```
org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [name] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:594)
```

But when I issue the same query from phpMyAdmin, it works fine. Also, if I remove either `at1.name` or `at2.name` from the `SELECT` statement, the query works in Hibernate. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving different alias name to your select columns like 
"SELECT ddm.image as col1, at1.name as col2, at2.name as col3"

It seems hibernate doesn't generate the different alias automatically. If the query results has same values this issue may happens.
Reference : https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/80